# Removing outliers within each group of a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, plyr

i have the following dataset in R

```
data <- structure(list(BatcBatchNo = structure(c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("Batch18200616", "Batch18200702", 
    "Batch18200703", "Batch18200704", "Batch18200705", "Batch18200708", "Batch18200709", 
    "Batch18200710", "Batch18200711", "Batch20200712", "Batch20200715", "Batch21200701", 
    "Batch21200703", "Batch21200704", "Batch21200705", "Batch21200706", "Batch21200708", 
    "Batch21200709", "Batch22200630", "Batch22200701", "Batch22200702", "Batch22200707", 
    "Batch23200620", "Batch23200701", "Batch23200702", "Batch23200703", "Batch23200704", 
    "Batch23200706", "Batch24200717", "Batch25200707", "Batch54200711", "Batch55200705", 
    "Batch55200706", "Batch55200707", "Batch56200701", "Batch56200702", "Batch56200704", 
    "Batch56200705", "Batch56200709", "Batch56200710", "Batch57200701", "Batch57200702", 
    "Batch57200703", "Batch57200704", "Batch57200706", "Batch57200708", "Batch57200709", 
    "Batch57200710", "Batch57200711", "Batch57200712", "Batch57200714", "Batch57200717", 
    "Batch58200701", "Batch58200702", "Batch58200703", "Batch58200704", "Batch58200705", 
    "Batch58200708", "Batch58200710", "Batch58200712", "Batch58200713", "Batch59200622", 
    "Batch59200701", "Batch59200702", "Batch59200704", "Batch59200705", "Batch59200706", 
    "Batch59200707", "Batch59200708", "Batch59200709", "Batch60200618", "Batch60200702", 
    "Batch60200705", "Batch60200708"), class = "factor"), SetValue = c(690, 
    690, 690, 690, 690, 690, 690, 690, 690, 690), ActualValue = c(705, 
    706, 706, 705, 705, 704, 704, 704, 705, 705), ONCondition = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 
    10L), class = "data.frame")

> data
     BatcBatchNo SetValue ActualValue ONCondition
1  Batch18200711      690         705        TRUE
2  Batch18200711      690         706        TRUE
3  Batch18200711      690         706        TRUE
4  Batch18200711      690         705        TRUE
5  Batch18200711      690         705        TRUE
6  Batch18200711      690         704        TRUE
7  Batch18200711      690         704        TRUE
8  Batch18200711      690         704        TRUE
9  Batch18200711      690         705        TRUE
10 Batch18200711      690         705        TRUE
```

i need to calculate standard deviation for each Batch & Set Value. But before calculating its standard deviation i need to remove the outliers in that Batch.

Means i need to perform following steps

1. Remove Outliers in Actual Value within each batch. Outliers to be calculated on batch to batch basis and not on overall dataset
2. Perform standard deviation on batch n Set value combined.

I was trying to use `dplyr` functions to calculation the standard deviation but then its not taking care of the outliers.

This code doest take care of outliers

```
Output= Data%>%
   group_by(BatchNo)%>%
     group_by(SetValue)%>%
      summarize(Mean= mean(ActualValue),SD= sd(ActualValue))
```

How do I proceed in this case.

Comment: Do you have any logic/condition to identify outliers?  It would've been great if you could have included desired output for the sample data given.

Comment: yes. We can eliminate that by setting values less than 1 percentile or greater than 99th percentile should be considered as outliers

Comment: this way every dataset has outliers! Consider the set 1,2,3,...,98,99,100.
According to your logic 1 and 100 would be outliers

Comment: yes that would be fine, considering 2 values as outliers as every batch has machine off condition which means 0 is outlier and current does spike up for some seconds which makes 100 percentile value as outlier. The issue is we dont know the upper cap in each batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `filter` to remove "outliers` accroding to the logic mentioned in the comments:

```
Data%>%
  group_by(BatchNo) %>%
  filter(ActualValue <= quantile(ActualValue, 0.99), ActualValue >= quantile(ActualValue, 0.01)) %>%
  group_by(BatchNo, SetValue) %>%
  summarize(Mean = mean(ActualValue), SD = sd(ActualValue))
```